# MYSQL Group together query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 512 entries in it (initially, this will increase with records at we add to it).  This table has columns:

- `id` (`id` is auto_incrementing and primary)
- `ip_address`
- `in_use` (`in_use` is bool, true / false)

Basically I have a list of addresses in this (like I said initially it's got 512)

I need to ask mysql to return rows not in use, but group them together by a set number (ie I need 11 free addresses),

However, this system will have rows marked false on the `in_use` col right next to others with true.

I need a way to grab a set amount of IP's the id being broken sequentially... example

```
ids => in_use
--------------
1 => false
2 => false
3 => false
4 => false
5 => false
6 => false
7 => false
8 => false
9 => true
10 => true
11 => false
12 => false
13 => false
14 => false
15 => false
16 => false
17 => false
18 => false
19 => false
20 => false
21 => false
22 => false
23 => false
```

Now if I query for 11 free addresses, closest to the top, it will bring back the list of id's 1 to 12 skipping over 9, this won't work for what I am trying to do :(

What I would like it to do is realize that 9 is in use so cannot use that, thus cannot make a sequential group and pick from 11 to 22... as that is the next available sequential set.

Is there any way to structure a query for this?

Answer (score 1):

Sample table for discussion

```
#drop table if exists ids;
create table ids (id int primary key, in_use bool);
insert ids values
(1,0),
(2,0),
(3,0),
(4,0),
(5,0),
(6,0),
(7,0),
(8,0),
(9,1),
(10,1),
(11,0),
(12,0),
(13,0),
(14,0),
(15,0),
(16,0),
(17,0),
(18,0),
(19,0),
(20,0),
(21,0),
(22,0),
(23,0);
```

The following query will give you all the possible sequence start and ends to satisfy the range size required (where clause at the end);

```
select seq_start, id seq_end
from
(
    select
      id,
      @start:=IF(in_use,null,IFNULL(@start,id)) seq_start,
      @rownum:=IF(@start is null, 0, @rownum+1) rownum
    from (select @start:=0, @rownum:=0) s
    cross join ids
    order by id
) numbered
where rownum = 11;
```